# javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string

Tags: outlook, character

While trying to READ the email addressee of an email coming from Outlook:

```
message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string ``'xxxxx@yyyyyy.com'''
  at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1269)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1091)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parseHeader(InternetAddress.java:658)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:701)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:534)
```

The problem is given by this character " ' " at the beginning and at the end of the email address. The problem is that for the outlook server this is a valid address but not for a MimeMessage, so when I am trying to retrieve it and all the checks are applied I am getting the exception.

Please note that I am not creating the message, I am just reading whatever is in the outlook inbox folder through:

```
Folder inbox = store.getFolder(.......);
messages = inbox.getMessages();
```

Any idea how to solve/workaround this?

Thank you very much
Sam

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you are using java mail version higher than 1.4 which by defaults enables strict RFC822 syntax

You could able to read email with quotes by disabling "strict" policy on [InternetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) something like this.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.mime.address.strict", "false");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, ....);
```

Or simply

```
new InternetAddress("...", false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this actually helped me! I put: props.setProperty("mail.mime.address.strict", "false")